# Redshift COPY failing to read tar.gz from S3. Error code 1216. Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x2f found at location 1

Tags: bash, awk, sed, amazon-redshift

#### tar --list

When I list the contents of the tar.gz file I get the following:

```bash
$ tar --list --verbose --file /tmp/tmp.tar.gz | head -5
drwxrwxr-x user/user     0 2015-07-22 19:51 ./
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 113376 2015-07-13 06:29 ./NASDAQ_20140324.txt
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 116101 2015-07-13 06:29 ./NASDAQ_20140602.txt
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 120710 2015-07-13 06:30 ./NASDAQ_20140822.txt
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 123969 2015-07-13 06:31 ./NASDAQ_20141104.txt
```

---

#### zcat

When I `zcat` the file I get:

```bash
$ zcat /tmp/tmp.tar.gz | head -5
./0000775000175000017500000000000012553663674010514 5ustar  useruser./NASDAQ_20140324.txt0000664000175000017500000033534012550547030013173 0ustar  useruserAAIT,D,20140324,31.1,31.29,30.97,31.11,14600
AAL,D,20140324,36.25,36.86,36.03,36.8,6514500
AAME,D,20140324,3.71,3.75,3.71,3.73,5900
AAOI,D,20140324,25.76,26.15,24.84,25.81,213300
AAON,D,20140324,19.2267,19.2933,18.8667,19.1667,149700
```

---

#### stl_load_errors

The issue from `stl_load_errors` (listing pertinent columns only) for the `<files>` found in the `s3://<bucket>/<key>` are:

```
filename        =>  <file>.tar.gz
line_number     =>  1
colname         =>  (empty)
type            =>  (empty)
col_length      =>  (empty)
position        =>  0
raw_line        =>  ./
raw_field_value =>  (empty)
err_code        =>  1216
err_reason      =>  Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x2f found at location 1
```

Breaking this down further:

- `error_code` of `1216` is [Invalid input line.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Load_Error_Reference.html)
- `error_reason` has `0x2f` which is the [forward slash UTF-8 character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2f/index.htm)

> *Note*: On `line_number` = `1`, at the `position` of `0`, the
>   `raw_line` has `./`, which apart from the period (`.`) is the forward
>   slash character mentioned in the `error_reason`

**This seems to be consistent with what the `zcat` output provides**, which has a malformed first line. Whether this is a red herring or not, I do not know.

---

**But wait, there's more...**

> The text files originally come zipped, so I convert the `zip` archive
>   files into `tar.gz` archive files in this manner ...

1. zip files are `unzip`ed into a temp dir
2. text files in the temp dir are transformed
   2.1. `sed` removes a header line from the file and pipes into ...
   2.2. `awk` prepends a column to the output and saves to a temp text file
   2.3. `mv` just renames the temp file to the original file name within the temp working directory
3. tar.gz file is create from the transformed temp files

#### 1.

```bash
unzip -q "${in_archive_file_path}" -d "${tmp_working_dir}"
```

#### 2.

```bash
for in_file_path in `find "${tmp_working_dir}" -type f -iname "*_????????.txt" | sort -n`;
do  
    sed -e "1{/^${quote_header_mask}/d;}" "${in_file_path}" |
    awk -v in_var="${exchange}" '{print in_var,$0}' OFS=, > "${tmp_working_dir}/tmp.txt"
    mv -f "${tmp_working_dir}/tmp.txt" "${in_file_path}"
done
```

and `quote_header_mask="<ticker>,<date>,<open>,<high>,<low>,<close>,<vol>"`

#### 3.

```bash
tar c -C "${tmp_working_dir}/" . | pigz --best -p4 > "${working_dir}/tmp.tar.gz"
mv -f "${working_dir}/tmp.tar.gz" "${out_file_path}"
```

`working_dir` is the parent to `tmp_working_dir`

---

#### COPY

```sql
copy source.quote_daily
(
    exchange_code
    ,ticker_code    
    ,date_key_local
    ,price_open     
    ,price_high     
    ,price_low      
    ,price_close    
    ,volume
)
from 's3://<bucket>/<key>' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<key value>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret key value>' 
delimiter  ','
gzip
trimblanks
compupdate off
statupdate off
;
```

---

#### Question(s)

1. Is `zcat` pointing me in the right direction with respect to what `Redshift` will "see" when decompressing the archive ... ?
2. ... which might mean my `tar.gz` creation script is screwing things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the data I was working with.

Some files had a different header than the one I had set for the variable `${quote_header_mask}` in part 2, so the header line was not being removed.

These files made it to the `COPY` command, and the failure was occurring because the headers still existed and my `COPY` makes no provision for any headers at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Redshift supports importing archived files(tar) for the COPY command. You should compress each file with gzip format and upload them to s3. The files on s3 should be like this.

```
s3://<bucket>/<key>/XXXXX.gz
s3://<bucket>/<key>/YYYYY.gz
...
```

You can copy all of gz files with a single COPY command by specifying the directory path like `from 's3://<bucket>/<key>/'`.

Comment: This is not correct. I have used the COPY command successfully in the past to import tar.gz files.

Comment: I tested on my environment again, but couldn't copy tar file(non-gzip) to Redshift correctly. It seems COPY just treats the specified file as a single file data, so you might copy tar file data other than the first line which contains archive information like filename list, permissions and so on.